# possible to make a DDL bigquery statement with airflow BigQueryOperator?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

Is it possible to make DDL statement (scripting) in Airflow BigQUeryOperator ?
Because script is OK on bigquery UI, but when running it on airflow 1.10.12 I have the classic error 'not found in location US' which is not helping me a lot.
I tried passing WRITE_DISPOSITION and CREATE_DISPOSITION as None, and also with default values.
It seems that it must be possible refering to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383391/how-can-you-create-a-view-using-the-bigqueryoperator-in-airflow)

Comment: Did you create the dataset?

Comment: yes destination dataset exists. Script is OK through UI.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it seems than DDL statement is OK with the operator.
But it's when I try scripting that I have an issue.
Does anyone had success with bigquery scripting in BigQueryOperator on airflow ?